Expected Value of sample mean and single observation
I'm trying to calculate the expected value of the autocovariance estimator,
$$\mathbb{E}(\hat{\gamma}(h)) = \mathbb{E} \left(\frac 1n\sum_{t=1}^{n-|h|}(X_{t+|h|}-\bar{X}_n)(X_t-\bar{X}_n)\right), \qquad h=0,\pm 1,\ldots, \pm(n-1).$$
My initial attempt is to rewrite the summation as
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}(\hat{\gamma}(h)) &= \mathbb{E} \left(\frac 1n\sum_{t=1}^{n-|h|}(X_{t+|h|}-\bar{X}_n)(X_t-\bar{X}_n)\right) \\
& = \mathbb{E} \left(\frac 1n\sum_{t=1}^{n-|h|}X_{t+|h|}X_t -\bar{X}_n(X_{t+|h|} + X_t) + \bar{X}_n^2\right) \\
& = \frac{n-|h|}{n} \mathbb{E}(\bar{X}_n^2) + \frac{1}{n}\sum_{t=1}^{n-|h|}\mathbb{E}(X_{t+|h|}X_t) - \frac 1n \mathbb{E} \left(\sum_{t=1}^{n-|h|} \bar{X}_n(X_{t+|h|} + X_t)\right)
\end{align*}
I'm not sure if this summation is correct, but if it is, can I use some property to simplify the expression $$\sum_{t=1}^{n-|h|} \bar{X}_n(X_{t+|h|} + X_t)$$ without assuming some specific property on $X_t$?
